# What are the Software/Hardware Problems with Ternary Computing?

Tags: binary, ternary

Ternary computing seems to be more efficient that binary since the number 3 is the integer with the highest radix economy, but there are issues in its implementation.

1) What are some software issues with ternary computing that might make it worse than binary.

2) What are some hardware issues with ternary computing that might make it unfeasible to construct a ternary computer.

For number 2, I have researched different hardware variations for ternary computers such as optical computing and such.

Comment: Just educated guess: binary gates are simple, ternary would be much more complex and less stable at high frequencies and sussceptible to input load/voltage changes (due to more unsaturated states) so its high likely ternary computer would be slower than binary at least unless ternary biased gates/parts are developed. from the SW side most algorithms are binary based so to take advantage of ternary ALU/CPU/whatever would need to rewrite/optimize them all with uncertain trade-offs/benefits. That is a lot of work with questionalble results not many are willing to invest in.

Comment: Anyway IIRC there where [ternary computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer) build in the past. But as we got binary gates and or switching transistors/diodes binary computers beat them all the time (at least to my knowledge)